# Measuring memory usage of executable run using golang

Tags: memory, go

How do I measure the amount of memory used by an executable which I run through the `os/exec` package in Golang? Is it better to do this through the OS itself?

Comment: Real-time or post-execution? `/usr/bin/time -f "%M" ls` could be used if you want the result.

Comment: Is there any cross-platform solution for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to do this through the OS itself. If you are on plan9 or posix, Go will return the usage values from the OS for you in the structure returned by [`ProcessState.SysUsage()`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#ProcessState.SysUsage).

```
cmd := exec.Command("command", "arg1", "arg2")
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
// check this type assertion to avoid a panic
fmt.Println("MaxRSS:", cmd.ProcessState.SysUsage().(*syscall.Rusage).Maxrss)
```

Note: different platforms may return this in bytes or kilobytes. Check `man getrusage` for details.

Comment: Any thoughts on a real-time solution? i.e., before the process has existed. I think `cmd.ProcessState` is only available after the program has terminated.

Comment: @KevinBullaughey: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879817/golang-os-exec-realtime-memory-usage. Everything is available in `/proc/$PID/smaps`